# Assign the scalar result of a SELECT statement to a variable or widget in Spark SQL (Databricks)

Tags: sql, apache-spark, databricks

I'm looking for the Spark SQL equivalent of the T-SQL `select @variable = AVG(something) FROM ...` construct.

I would like to assign the scalar returned from `select avg(year) from values ("John", 33), ("Karen", 20), ("Gladys", 25) as data(name, year)` to a variable or widget, and use it the `where` condition of later queries.

The [reference on widgets](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/widgets.html) shows how to do this for dropdown lists, but not for simple text widgets. All the text widget examples assign constants, not dynamic values.

This is in a pure SQL Databricks notebook so I'd prefer a vanilla SQL solution if one exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set` to set variables, and recall them using `${var}`:

```
spark.sql('set avg_var = (select avg(year) from values ("John", 33), ("Karen", 20), ("Gladys", 25) as data(name, year))')

spark.sql("select ${avg_var}").show()
+----------------+
|scalarsubquery()|
+----------------+
|            26.0|
+----------------+
```

In pure SQL it will look like

```
set avg_var = (select avg(year) from values ("John", 33), ("Karen", 20), ("Gladys", 25) as data(name, year));

select ${avg_var};
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, @mck!
When I run your pure SQL example, it appears to store the actual text of the select statement in avg_var, instead of the value of the calculation.
So the value of avg_var is "`(select avg(year) from values ("John", 33), ("Karen", 20), ("Gladys", 25) as data(name, year))`", and not 26.

Is there a setting to change this behavior?

Comment: Hmm, I'm unable to reproduce. I use Spark 3 and tested on spark-sql shell.

Comment: The spark.sql version works, the pure SQL one does what I described above. Both running in a Databricks notebook with Spark 3.0.1. Could be a Databricks issue, then. Thank you, though!